# django url doesn't work fine for me when using class based view

Tags: django

I am new to Django and now i am using Django2.2.
The scenario is when user click profile option on menu, and it will take user to their user profile

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(auth.models.AbstractUser):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path,
                              max_length=100,
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              default='account_users/default/profile_image/default.png')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "account_user"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**template**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'account:user_profile_detail' username=userprofile.username %}" class="btn btn-simple">Profile</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("profile/<str:username>/", views.UserDetail.as_view(), name="user_profile_detail"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class UserDetail(DetailView):
    model = models.UserProfile
    template_name = "userprofile_detail.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(
            userprofile__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
        )
```

it shows me this following error :

AttributeError at /account/profile/sm10547/
Generic detail view UserDetail must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8000/account/profile/sm10547/
Django Version: 2.2.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
Generic detail view UserDetail must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py in get_object, line 47
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.2

> updated :  sorry i update current situation here , now the structure
>   is :

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(auth.models.AbstractUser):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path,
                              max_length=100,
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                         default='account_users/default/profile_image/default.png')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "account_user"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**template**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'account:user_profile_detail' username=userprofile.username %}" class="btn btn-simple">Profile</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("profile/<slug:username>/", views.UserDetail.as_view(), name="user_profile_detail"),
]
```

**view.py**

```
class UserDetail(DetailView):
    model = models.UserProfile
    template_name = "userprofile_detail.html"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'

    def get_queryset(self)  :
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username"))
```

then it will throw error :

```
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, image, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, posts, user_permissions, username
```

do i really need to add slug field? or any way is better for me to deal with this error? thanks all !

Comment: sorry for foramt is not good, first time post question here

Answer (score 0):

This error throws because it expect a slug field or pk field
Change here

```
class UserDetail(DetailView):
    model = models.UserProfile
    template_name = "userprofile_detail.html"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

In url.py

```
path("profile/<slug:username>/", views.UserDetail.as_view(), name="user_profile_detail"),
```

In views.py

```
return queryset.filter(username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username"))
```

Lean more [slug_url_kwarg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg)

Comment: thanks shafik for your answer , but after i add thar line, it still show me this error :
-----------------------------------
Cannot resolve keyword 'userprofile' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, image, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, posts, user_permissions, username

Comment: thanks shafik, i tried updated answer to change url to path("profile/<slug:username>/", views.UserDetail.as_view(), name="user_profile_detail"), 

it still shows me the same above error : ------------- Cannot resolve keyword 'userprofile' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, image, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, posts, user_permissions, username

Comment: problem is here `return queryset.filter(
            userprofile__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
        )`

Comment: haha after i change it , it becomes another error :----------Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, image, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, posts, user_permissions, username

Comment: sorry another question , why change to username__iexact, doesn't it need to use model__field__iexact format?  sorry for so many question haha